# How to export datatable in HTML format?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, html-table, data-export

I am using primefaces 5.0 jar files. I searched on google and found that primefaces datatable is not supported to export html format. its support only csv, xls, pdf and xml format. but i want to achieve this functionality so any one know how to achieve this functionality.

Is there any alternative way to export datatable in html format?

Comment: @BalusC, How to produce desirable HTML output to another xhtml page?

Comment: There are some things in _my_ dictionary: 'search engine', 'try', 'experiment', etc. ;-). @BalusC: I doubt it is obivous for the average JSF user on how to 'download' a different xhtml page via a download button.

Comment: @Kukeltje, Why BalusC deleted his comment that comment was helpful I was trying same. any way I'll try and experiment :)

Comment: @Kukeltje We are here to help the people not to comment what all benefits SO got from your comments ? Tell me one.

Comment: intial comment on the question above removed... Not relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not to difficult to add an additional format to the PrimeFaces exporter.

Just override two classes in PrimeFaces (you can put the overridden classes in your own application with the same name and package):

- [org.primefaces.component.export.ExporterType.java](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/ExporterType.java)
- [org.primefaces.component.export.ExporterFactory.java](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/ExporterFactory.java)

In the first you add "HTML" and in the second you add an additional `case` in the switch:

```
case HTML:
    exporter = new HTMLExporter();
break;
```

This `HTMLExporter` does **not** exist, and you need to use one of the [existing exporters](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export) as an example to create your own `HTMLExporter` (if you put it in a different package than `org.primefaces.component.export`, you might need to also add an import statement in the ExporterFactory, but that is hopefully obvious)

Comment: I tried same thing but ExporterFactory class throwing error because HTMLExporter(); method doesn't exist. I tried another exporter method with help of IDE but HTMLExporter(); method is not coming by default and if write manually then throwing error.

Comment: You have to **create** the HTMLExporter and implement the code (that is 'work' and beyond the scope of the answer) AND make sure it is **not** also in a jar (like the PF one) otherwise you have no guarantee that it is loaded fist. Put it in the WEB-INF/classes (so it is loaded before the PF implementation) ...

Comment: Where I will get HTMLExporter code so that I can use? And sorry kukeltje, I'm asking to much doubt

Comment: Big task? Depends on what you want. PDF exporter is the most extensive and if you use that as an example,  you will have a basic solution in one hour and a more complex on in half a day. If that is a big task, then find another job (or find a different solution)

Comment: File is downloading in HTML Format and data also coming but I need to set output format also because data is not in proper manner in html file...Thanks for helping and you are genius :) , I'll do rest of modification.

Comment: I'm no genius, not by a long shot (although both my IQ an EQ are both a descent amount above average). I'm just curious by nature and  read a lot of existing code to learn things (it is so easy using modern ide's), read forums and SO to know what problems others have and learn from that for the future.  And if it works, you can always create a pull request so it might get included in PrimeFaces